# Windowsでの「ファイル作成日時」を変更する方法

Tags: go

Windows上で、特定のファイルの作成日時を変更したいのですが、その方法が分かりません。

最終アクセス時刻と最終更新日時は `os.Chtimes()` で変更できますが、作成日時を変更する方法はありますでしょうか。PowerShellを呼ぶしかないかなと考えています。

Comment: Windows でしたら、`syscall.SetFileTime()` が利用できるかと思います。具体的な実装例としては[このコード](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21541#issuecomment-323837977)が参考になるかと。

Comment: @metropolis 教えて頂いた実装例を元に、後ほど自己回答をしておきます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己回答です（metropolisさんのコメントから）。

[このコード](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21541#issuecomment-323837977)を元に、`Filetime` の作成部分だけ書き直した例になります。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    filename := os.Args[1]

    handle, err := syscall.CreateFile(
        syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(filename),
        syscall.FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
        syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE|syscall.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        nil,
        syscall.OPEN_EXISTING,
        syscall.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error opening %q: %v", filename, err)
        return
    }

    defer syscall.CloseHandle(handle)

    // 全てを現在時刻にする例
    t := time.Now().UnixNano()

    ctime := syscall.NsecToFiletime(t)
    atime := syscall.NsecToFiletime(t)
    mtime := syscall.NsecToFiletime(t)

    err = syscall.SetFileTime(handle, &ctime, &atime, &mtime)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error setting file %q time: %v", filename, err)
    }
}
```